# simple unittest.FunctionTestCase() example

Tags: python, python-unittest, assert

I have an existing python script that I'd like to test with python's unittest libary, specifically using unittest.**FunctionTestCase()**

Can anyone provide a simple 'actual' example of how someone might do this?

cheers for help

```
    def test_something(self):
        testCase1 = unittest.FunctionTestCase(existingFunctionToLoadWebPage)
        testCase2 = unittest.FunctionTestCase(existingFunctionToSubmitWebForm)
        testSuite = unittest.TestSuite((testCase1, testCase2))

        self.assertEqual(suite.countTestCases(), 2)
        # Validate the two existing functions above worked, even though then don't return anything:
        self.assertEqual(suite.testCase1)
        self.assertEqual(suite.testCase2)
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `FunctionTestCase`? Is it just "I want to test a function, and `FunctionTestCase` sounds like a class designed to do that"? If so, you've misunderstood what `FunctionTestCase` is, and you should just write a normal test with `unittest.TestCase`.

Comment: Have you read the documentation?  https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html. And as pointed out by @user2357112, you don't want to use this if you're writing new tests.

Comment: Okay I will try with unittest.TestCase. 

Sorry perhaps I gave wrong context. the functions to be tested already exist, by which I understood the documentation to suggest FunctionTestCase.

Comment: When the docs say "wrap an existing test function", that doesn't mean wrapping an existing function that you want to test. It means wrapping an existing *test function* - a function that, when executed, performs testing. It's meant as an adapter around really old non-`unittest` test code.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. This was a misunderstanding on my part. Now it makes more sense.